# How to install NVM on Z shell WSL ubuntu (Zsh)

Tags: zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nvm

I want to install Oh My Zsh on Ubuntu in Windows Subsystem for Linux WSL

Answer (score 2):

Using Zsh, open the ~/.zshrc file and update the plugins:
`plugins=(git nvm)`